# I tried to run the app in the emulator but its not showing the first activity. it just opens and shows a white screen

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-logcat

the logcat-

```
    --------- beginning of system
10-24 17:40:01.419    1309-1675/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]  flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.apsdevelopers.mr.meteout/.mottoscreen (has extras)} from uid 10008 on display 0
10-24 17:40:01.665    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:01.950    2026-2037/? I/art﹕ CollectorTransition marksweep + semispace GC freed 1303(40KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 42% free, 697KB/1209KB, paused 149.640ms total 149.640ms
10-24 17:40:01.961    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:02.284    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:02.444    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:02.595    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:02.733    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:02.873    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:03.152    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:03.257    1309-1328/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 411 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:03.445    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:03.537    1309-1328/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:03.606    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:03.892    1917-1917/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:03.888    1309-1328/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-24 17:40:04.597    1309-1328/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.apsdevelopers.mr.meteout/.mottoscreen: +2s813ms
10-24 17:40:04.814    1309-1328/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

my first activity(mottoscreen) java file -

```
package com.apsdevelopers.mr.meteout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;




public class mottoscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mottoscreen, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {


        if (v.getId() == R.id.bLOGIN) {
            Intent I = new Intent(mottoscreen.this, circles.class);
            startActivity(I);
        }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

my first activity(mottoscreen) XML file-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".mottoscreen"
android:background="#9acef6fe"
android:contextClickable="false"
android:id="@+id/activity_mottoscreen">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="#SELL SCRAP ?"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bLOGIN"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bLOGIN" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="#DONATE TO CHILDREN ?"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:password="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PROCEED"
    android:id="@+id/bLOGIN"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:background="#e33a9179"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="#HELP THE OLD ?"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:password="false"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="CLICK PROCEED TO MAKE THE WORLD A BETTER PLACE..."
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:password="false"
    android:textColor="#d95c5c5d"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bLOGIN"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i dont know what is happening . i have tried to run this app on a real device too but it opens up and doesnt show anything. someone please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You missed setContenView(R.layout.mottoscreen) in onCreate.
Please set the view to the activity inside the onCreate of Activity.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mottoscreen_layout);
    }
```

Comment: @APS  I tried with code you posted in the question and following is result on genymotion emulator... http://i.imgur.com/RcKRWSq.png?1  make sure that you do not have theme or style that is affecting the layout...can you post please post your manifest file in the question.

Comment: thanks @shadow. It works now. after updating the code i was trying it in my emulator which showed no change but when i checked it in a real device it worked,